# How to add custom text to all email templates?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, transactional-mail

I want to add a custom text input field to `admin/Marketing/Email templates/Add New Template`.

This new text input should save it's value to the current email template content which I am creating.

I want to achieve that text appears after all rest content of the email template.

For a while, I'm trying to google it, unfortunately, I can't find what I am looking for.

Does anyone have an idea?